# where are the windows gvim language default settings?

Tags: windows-7, language, gvim

I am running gvim 8.1 on w7 x64 US english.
My windows system regional setting is Germany though as I am located in Germany and I want German currency and date settings.
When I run vim and type :lang I get the following:

```
Current language: "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=C;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
```

Where are these values coming from and where can I change them?
I want utf8 and not 1252 code pages.

Comment: Language settings should be in file .vimrc or _vimrc. Can you find this file, please?

Comment: on my windows _vimrc is at C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim.  This sources vimrc_example.vim which sources defaults.vim. None of those has a language setting for German_Germany.1252. So I am still puzzled where this setting comes from.

Comment: You have set your language to German and your location to Germany. Also Windows uses 1252 charset by default. I don't want to sound rude, but what were you expecting? What else could it be? I don't know exactly how vim finds the language, but I assume it goes for what is set by Windows. To change the encoding you need to add the language settings to the _vimrc file to use German_Germany.UTF-8.

Comment: Did you manage to change your encoding from cp1252 to utf-8?

Comment: In the meantime I have upgraded to windows 10 but the problem is still there. I have not set my language to German but just the adpated the currency and time notation to Germany. I have also put set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8
set encoding=utf-8 in my _vimrc. But if I type :lang I still get: LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=C;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=
English_United States.1252"
Do I have to change every value seperately to utf-8 or is there a general setting?

Comment: @Aulis: My question was just where the defaults settings come from. To my knowledge windows uses UTF for quite a while. If the defaults are not set in a config file but derived somehow from the operating system then of course I need to set/override them to my desired values. So the question is: How and where?

Answer (score 0):

These values are just your current language settings. I have changed mine to english (US) with the following lines on my `.vimrc`:

```
language en_US
language messages en_US
language ctype en_US
language time en_US
let $LANG = 'en_US'
```

See `:h lang` for more details